# Toggling Shield UI ASP.NET chart dataPointText property at runtime

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I am using related Shield UI ASP.NET Charts on a web page. What I need is to be able to provide the user the option to choose whether to show the dataPointText  or not. For that purpose I have put a checkbox below the second grid and am trying to use the following code:

```
        detailChartElement.shieldChart($.extend(initialOptions, {
            primaryHeader: {
                text: headerText
            },
            if (document.getElementById("CheckBox1").checked == true){
                seriesSettings: {
                    line: {
                        dataPointText: {
                            enabled: true,
                            borderColor: 'red',
                            borderWidth:3
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
```

but when I put the code and none of the grids on the page shows. I checked quite carefully the code but don’t see any missed out commas or anything that should prevent it from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are making is not syntactical but conceptual. Within the code that creates the chart:

```
   detailChartElement.shieldChart($.extend(initialOptions, {
   }));
```

you may place nothing but the properties of the Shield UI ASP.NET chart and their properties. You may not have any logical checks like IF(). However you may have additional variables and their values. 
With this in mind you could use the following workaround:

1. In the function you use to recreate the chart you place the following code:

   ```
       var showlabels = document.getElementById("CheckBox1").checked;
   ```
2. Than, you put the series settings code in the chart creation routine:

   ```
               seriesSettings: {
                   line: {
                       dataPointText: {
                           enabled: showlabels,
                           borderColor: 'red',
                           borderWidth:bordersize
                       }
                   }
               },
   ```

The properties and values will be always there, however they will be enabled only when the checkbox is checked.